# Issues using Intel XDK sendSMS function with on click event

Tags: cordova-3

I have been trying to get the sms application to load on my Samsung

Note 4 that I am using to test my application developed using the

intel xdk ide(Cordova Application). Below is the on click event that I

am using that is not working as expected.

```
//.numbers class element is created dynamically
$(document).on("click",".numbers a",function(e){

   //stop link from refreshing
   e.preventDefault();

   //the alert below will work when uncommented
   //alert("event works");

   //The function call below will not work.
   //note I am using a real number in my app
   //and it will work if I call if from another button on click event 
   intel.xdk.device.sendSMS("hello","8161234567");

});
```

Thank You,
Larry J Lane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the  problem. It was an array.push
 function call that was missing a closing ).